# Laravel api works in browser but not on android app

Tags: laravel, google-cloud-console, laravel-7

Laravel api works fine from browser but unable to respond from android app. Is there any configuration changes in laravel api?

Comment: post your route, which is belongs to this api call

Comment: unable to work any route in app but works in browser

Comment: post your codes from `.../routes/web.php`

Comment: <?php

Route::post('login', 'Wipeit\Product\LoginController@login');

Route::post('signup', 'Wipeit\Product\LoginController@signup');

Route::post('checkMobile', 'Wipeit\Product\LoginController@checkMobile');

Route::post('checkOtp', 'Wipeit\Product\LoginController@checkOtp');

Route::post('checkUsername', 'Wipeit\Product\LoginController@checkUsername');

Route::post('changePassword','Wipeit\Product\LoginController@changePassword');

Route::get('getMachineLocations','Wipeit\Product\ViewController@getMachineLocations');